# Change dataset resolution to match another dataset

Tags: python, numpy, resolution

I have two datasets: one modelled and one observational. I need to get the observational dataset to the same resolution as the model.

Currently the model data had 100 longitude and 100 latitude points, so each datapoint is 1.8 degrees by 3.6 degrees.

I've tried the following, but the datapoints don't quite match up so I can't concatenate the datasets.

```
import xarray as xa
import numpy as np
import cmocean.cm as cm
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeat


# =============================================================================
#  Step 1: Get data
# =============================================================================
    
data_model = xa.open_dataset("PD_tavg_out_diss_5.nc",decode_times = False)

sal_obs_data = xa.open_dataset("sal_obs_NS_all.nc",decode_times = False)
temp_obs_data = xa.open_dataset("temp_obs_NS_all.nc",decode_times = False)

data_obs = xa.merge([sal_obs_data,temp_obs_data])
data_obs = data_obs.rename(lon = "longitude",
                           lat = "latitude")




data_extract = data_model[["O_cons_temp","O_abs_sal"]]
long1 = data_extract.longitude.values
long1[long1>180]-=360
data_extract["longitude"] = long1
data_sorted = data_extract.sortby("longitude")
    
    
long2 = data_obs.longitude.values
long2[long2>180]-=360
data_obs["longitude"] = long2
data_sorted_obs = data_obs.sortby("longitude")


long_max = 1.8
long_min = -1.8
lat_max = 60.3
lat_min = 54.9
dep_max = 100
dep_min = 0
tim_max = 35422.0
tim_min = 35421.0 

def extract_shelf_sea(long_max, long_min, 
                      lat_max, lat_min,
                      dep_max, dep_min,
                      tim_max, tim_min):

# =============================================================================
#  Step 3: Extract data
# =============================================================================

    extract_model_data = data_sorted.sel(longitude = slice(long_min,long_max),
                                         latitude = slice(lat_min,lat_max),
                                         depth = slice(dep_min,dep_max),
                                         time = slice(tim_min,tim_max))


    extract_obs_data = data_obs.sel(time = data_obs.time,
                                    longitude = slice(long_min,long_max),
                                    latitude = slice(lat_min,lat_max))
    
    new_lon = np.linspace(extract_obs_data.longitude[0],extract_obs_data.longitude[7],extract_model_data.sizes['longitude'])
    new_lat = np.linspace(extract_obs_data.latitude[0],extract_obs_data.latitude[10],extract_model_data.sizes['latitude'])
    obs_interpolated = extract_obs_data.interp(latitude = new_lat, longitude = new_lon)
    
    
    extract_obs_depth = obs_interpolated.sel(depth = extract_model_data.depth, method="nearest")
```

Observation outputs:

```
extract_obs_depth
Out[178]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (depth: 2, latitude: 4, longitude: 2, time: 12)
Coordinates:
  * depth      (depth) float64 15.07 82.92
  * time       (time) float32 480.5 481.5 482.5 483.5 ... 489.5 490.5 491.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 54.25 56.42 58.58 60.75
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -1.75 1.75
Data variables:
    salt       (time, depth, latitude, longitude) float64 nan 34.56 ... 35.38
    temp       (time, depth, latitude, longitude) float64 nan 6.586 ... 8.907
```

Model outputs:

```
extract_model_data
Out[179]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (depth: 2, latitude: 4, longitude: 2, time: 12)
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) float64 3.542e+04 3.542e+04 ... 3.542e+04 3.542e+04
  * longitude    (longitude) float64 -1.8 1.8
  * latitude     (latitude) float64 54.9 56.7 58.5 60.3
  * depth        (depth) float64 17.5 82.5
Data variables:
    O_cons_temp  (time, depth, latitude, longitude) float64 5.615 ... 7.437
    O_abs_sal    (time, depth, latitude, longitude) float64 33.28 ... 35.21
```

Any suggestions for how I can get the latitude and longitude to match perfectly would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

By the way, unfortunately I can't upload the datasets as they're too big.

Comment: Why not take the model itself (that produced the model data) and plug in the exact latitude and longitude values that you need?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the model code itself. I can just run simulations on it... This would otherwise be the perfect solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about interpolating the observational dataset to the coordinates of the modelled dataset?

In particular, you could use the [`RectSphereBivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectSphereBivariateSpline.html#scipy-interpolate-rectspherebivariatespline) from Scipy module, that directly interpolates *structured* data (data defined in a regular grid, as it seems is your case) in spherical coordinates (I'm assuming here your other dimensions - time and depth- match between datasets; if not you would have to perform several interpolations).

Take a look at the example in the documentation I linked above, and if you have any doubts feel free to ask; I myself have used that function once or twice, and if I recall correctly, the documentation is wrong in one of the coordinates parameters (I think it was the `v` parameter, which instead of being defined in the `[-pi, pi]` interval as the docs says, it actually must be in `[0, 2pi]` -take this with a pinch of salt though).